# Checking what commands were run on windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-command-prompt

From time to time a cmd windows popps up (or two of them) for a split second I cannot track what was started. Is there a way to monitor the cmd/powershell window? Sysmon?

Or is there a way to force cmd window to not close when command finishes?

The main issue is that I cannot see what command was started

Comment: Sysmon would work. An alternative would be procmon and keep it running until the window pops up.

Comment: Will it show me what command was started?

Comment: Yes, both will. Sysmon shows it in the eventlog, procmon shows it in the process details. For a one of situation, procmon would be the easier choice. Do make sure you don't hang up your computer by letting the log grow to large.

Answer (score 2):

For a one of situation, procmon would be the easiest choice
[image]

1. Disable the registry, file and network activity to minimize the amount of logging.
2. Make sure the process activity is enabled
3. start capturing and wait for the popup *(end capturing once the popup has, well, popped up)*
4. double click the process
5. get the command line

Comment: more than I wished for :)

Comment: @koller23 - I'm curious what it is :). I remember a similar issue on my machine that turned out to be a Windows update problem *(nothing to worry about but annoying)*.